# ¿Como ingresar arrays por constructor? Arrays java poo

Tags: java, array, poo

Debo hacer un programa de ingresar arrays en el main y luego mostrar el numero mas su posición , quise ingresar arrays por el constructor y no me deja. Hay otra forma de hacerlo?

```
public class IngresoDeEnteros {

private int numeros[];
private int dimension = 10;


public IngresoDeEnteros(int numeros []) {
    this.numeros = numeros;
    this.numeros = new int[dimension];
}

public void mostrarArrays() {

    int posicion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

        posicion = i;


        System.out.println("vector : " +numeros[i] + "indice : "+ posicion);
    }


}
```

}

```
public class PruebaIngresoDeEnteros {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IngresoDeEnteros array1[] = new IngresoDeEnteros{5, 10, 12,33 ,26 ,15,86,47,78,109};

    array1.mostrarArrays();


}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varios errores de lógica y de sintaxis en tu código:

- <s>`dimension`</s> no pinta nada en la clase si piensas pasarle al constructor un array ya lleno con cualquier dimensión. Lo único que haría sería capar tu clase, limitándola a aceptar arrays de esa dimensión y de ninguna otra
- En el constructor anulas el futuro array de números que le pasarías, cuando haces esto: <s>`this.numeros = new int[dimension];`</s>
- En la prueba estás usando mal el constructor: <s>`new IngresoDeEnteros{5, 10, 12,33 ,26 ,15,86,47,78,109};`</s>. Debes construir bien el array de números y una vez construido, pasarlo al constructor, usando además los paréntesis.
- En `mostrarArrays()`, la variable <s>`position`</s> es redundante. La usas para algo que `i` ya hace.

Corrigiendo todo eso, tendremos entonces:

#### Prueba

```
public class PruebaIngresoDeEnteros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = new int[] {5, 10, 12,33 ,26 ,15,86,47,78,109};
        IngresoDeEnteros array1 = new IngresoDeEnteros(intArray);
    }
}
```

#### Clase

```
public class IngresoDeEnteros {

    private int numeros[];

    public IngresoDeEnteros(int numeros []) {
        this.numeros = numeros;
    }

    public void mostrarArrays() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("vector : " +numeros[i] + " indice : "+ i);
        }
    }

}
```

#### Resultado:

```
vector : 5 indice : 0
vector : 10 indice : 1
vector : 12 indice : 2
vector : 33 indice : 3
vector : 26 indice : 4
vector : 15 indice : 5
vector : 86 indice : 6
vector : 47 indice : 7
vector : 78 indice : 8
vector : 109 indice : 9
```

Comment: Las partes tachadas hacen que no se entienda bien la idea.. pero la respuesta es correcta

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias por tu comentario. Uso las palabras tachadas para indicar al OP que no lo haga así. Dado que él conoce el contenido de su código, comprenderá que eso está mal, de hecho, no interesa mucho que se entienda lo que hay escrito ahí, cuanto que lo que está ahí escrito está mal y es causa de error y mal funcionamiento. Esa es la idea (para mi) de tachar las palabras.

Comment: Yo lo entiendo.. OP tambien.. pero el proximo que venga?? ojo es mi vision particular. Igual esta excelente la respuesta (lo vuelvo a decir)

Comment: @gbianchi esa es mi propia convención de respuesta :-) . Creo que cualquier otro que venga entenderá la idea. En este caso, todo lo que está tachado sobra, de hecho, no aparece en el código de la respuesta. Pude también sólo mencionarlo, pero cuando es alguien que dice que está empezando me gusta demostrar de alguna manera, cuando es posible, cuál es exactamente la parte de su código que está errada.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @A.Cedano por marcar mi error lo voy a tener en cuenta , Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien tu problema esto se solucionaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public class IngresoDeEnteros
{
    private int numeros[];

    public IngresoDeEnteros(int numeros [])
    {
        this.numeros = new int[numeros.length];
        System.arraycopy(numeros, 0, this.numeros, 0, numeros.length);
    }
    public void mostrarArrays()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("vector: " +numeros[i] + " indice : " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Luego ...

```
public class PruebaIngresoDeEnteros
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ints[] = {5, 10, 12,33 ,26 ,15,86,47,78,109};
        IngresoDeEnteros array = new IngresoDeEnteros(ints);

        array.mostrarArrays();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

public class PruebaIngresoDeEnteros {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1={5, 10, 12,33 ,26 ,15,86,47,78,109};
    IngresoDeEnteros met = new IngresoDeEnteros(array1);
    met.mostrarArrays();
}
```

}

---

public class IngresoDeEnteros {

```
private int numeros[];
private final int dimension = 10;

public IngresoDeEnteros(int numeros[]) {
    this.numeros = new int[dimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        this.numeros[i] = numeros[i];
    }
}

public void mostrarArrays() {

    int posicion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

        posicion = i;

        System.out.println("vector : " + numeros[i] + " indice : " + posicion);
    }

}
```

}

tenias que crear primero tu arreglo para luego enviarlo, no puedes enviar valores peor aun con corchetes, se suele usar parentesis :D

Comment: Gracias , tenes razón me había olvidado de los paréntesis jajaja Saludos :D